# MVC.NET Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I want to add a new route to my Web Api, which will read various ids and then filter a bunch of books.

So the final url should read something like `http://localhost/api/books/1/1/1/1`

Now I have added a route to my `RouteConfig` as follows :-

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BookFilter",
            url: "api/books/{author}/{title}/{genre}/{isbn}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Books", action = "BookFilter" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

I also added the following in my `BooksController`:-

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<BookDTO> BookFilter(int authorId, int titleId, int genreId, int isbn)
    {
        //filter books here
        return db.Books.ProjectTo<BookDTO>();
    }
```

However when I try to reach the page, I get a 404.

What do I need to do to reach my page?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: any idea of `attribute routing`?

Comment: yes I do have an idea, its just I have not done this for a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API and MVC are independent frameworks which each have separate types. The likely reason your route is not working is that you are confusing the two. Specifically, for it to work as you configured, you would need an MVC controller (that is, a controller that inherits `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`).

So, assuming you want to go with Web API as your question would indicate, you first need to ensure the correct definition of your controller. It should inherit from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`.

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult BookFilter(string author, string title, string genre, string isbn)
    {
        return Ok("Successful result");
    }
}
```

Next, you need to put your routing in the `WebApiConfig.cs` file, not in the `RouteConfig.cs` file. Don't forget to remove your route from the `RouteConfig.cs` file.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "BookFilter", 
            routeTemplate: "api/books/{author}/{title}/{genre}/{isbn}", 
            defaults: new { controller = "Books", action = "BookFilter" });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

You also need to ensure that the call to `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` is in your application startup path (by default in `Global.asax`).

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the same parameter name in your action (eg. change *author* to *authorId*):

Optionally, you can also specify default values for these parameters at your RouteConfig, as follows:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BookFilter",
            url: "api/books/{authorId}/{titleId}/{genreId}/{isbn}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Books", action = "BookFilter", authorId= UrlParameter.Optional, titleId = UrlParameter.Optional, genreId = UrlParameter.Optional, isbn = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<BookDTO> BookFilter(int authorId, int titleId, int genreId, int isbn)
    {
        //filter books here
        return db.Books.ProjectTo<BookDTO>();
    }
```

Comment: tried your changes but still not reaching the page.  Still getting a 404

Comment: 1) You don't need to specify defaults for every parameter. When you don't specify defaults, it makes the URL parameters required (which is likely preferable in this case). 2) `UrlParameter.Optional` can only be used 1 time per route and it *must* be the right-most parameter. 3) This is the wrong place to configure Web API routes. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37570381/181087).